# .change() with case

Tags: jquery, case, each

is it possible to add a case statement to that? The thing is that now it takes the value from the droplist and writes it to #shop_price. I want to add a statement that when it receives for example "door", instead of writing that, it would write something else (eg. price:).

> ```
> $("select.category").change(function () {
>  var str = "";
>  $("select.category option:selected").each(function () {
>  str += $(this).text();
>  });
>  $("#shop_price").text(str);
>  })
>  .change();
> ```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, do you have any problems with that? You could also use some kind of a look-up map: `var map = {'door': 'price'};`.

Comment: are you working with a single drop down? or a group of select elements that share a `.category` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are talking about a single-select dropdown, you can do it much easier using [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```
$("select.category").change(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    switch(value) {
        case "door":
             // whatever
             break;
        default:
             $("#shop_price").text(value);
             break;
    }
}).change();
```

If there is going to be a lot of special cases (otherwise why use `switch` instead of `if`?), you can make a map:

```
$("select.category").change(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();

    // This map has function values to give you maximum flexibility on how
    // you want to handle "special" cases. Here, I 'll show an alert.
    var map = {
        // note that you can access value normally inside these functions
        "door": function() { alert("I don't like doors!"); }
        // other special cases here
    };

    if(map[value]) {
        map[value]();
    }
    else {
        $("#shop_price").text(value);
    }
}).change();
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters, unless your `<select>` allows multiple selections using the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method is much faster/easier. e.g.

```
var str = $('select.category').val();
```

To answer your question though, you can use a switch within either the each (if the each is necessary) or after you assign str.

```
switch ($('select.category').val())
{
  case 'door':
    $('#shop_price').text('Price:');
    break;
  //...
}
```

Comment: this is the closest but it works only after reloading the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("select.category").change(function () {
    var str = "";
    $("option:selected", this).each(function () {
        var text = $(this).text();
        str += (text == 'door') ? 'price' : text;
    });
    $("#shop_price").text(str);
}).change();
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/QdZR6/)